# How to change Tabview at runtime .?

Tags: android, tabs, tabview

I want to change Tab view on click on that tab at run time in android.

When i m click in Favourites tab then automatically this tab image like Home tab..

Please help me in this.

like this 
Before

[image]

And after

[image]

Examples please...

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1):

To  automatically switch between the tab icon images when the tab state changes, use an xml file placed in drawable folder of resources as the tab indicator resource.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">   
 <!-- When selected, use grey -->   
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/home" android:state_selected="true" />   
 <!-- When not selected, use white-->    
<item android:drawable="@drawable/favorites" />
</selector>
```

Please check [Tab Layout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have one example in that not explained same as your requirements but using this OR after changing some condition OR adding some condition you will got your solution.

If we want to change tab color or images or text color at runtime then we used this code.

```
for(int i=0;i<host.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
{
   host.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_bg);
   TextView tv = (TextView) host.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title); //Unselected Tabs
   tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
}
host.getTabWidget().getChildAt(host.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_active_bg);// selected
TextView tv = (TextView) host.getCurrentTabView().findViewById(android.R.id.title); //for Selected Tab
tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
```

In this code **host.getTabWidget().getChildCount()** return the total number of your tab widgets. For example here as you display image 4 tabs are there.

I hope it helps you. Gud luck. :)